# How to create a send email button for my homepage in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I have an email button but it will open microsoft outlook when I'm trying to send the email. So I got 2 questions:

How do I correctly implement an email button in Magento?

I want to show the message you normally get when sending an email via contact form.(Success message)

```
<form id="contact" action="mailto:123@gmail.com" method="post"> 
<div class="send-button cl"><button type="submit">Send</button></div></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, when you use a mailto link to send email it is handled by their local browser/system.  Whatever their default app is to send email will open up.

You can't send the success message until the email is sent and when the local system handles it you don't know when or if it was sent.

You have a couple of obvious options:  Leave the mailto and let the local system handle it (do it as an A tag, not a form).  Otherwise, you need a form that is submitted and handled by some php and from that php you can forward them wherever you want them to go.